# Honda Odyssey engine cut out

Tags: engine, honda, ac

I have a 1997 Honda Odyssey automatic, it stopped running in the middle of the road and when I tried starting it again it made a loud whining sound, then I turned the key off and tried again and it started, what could the problem be?

Comment: Perhaps a seized AC compressor clutch? Did the AC work before the stall-out and does it work now?

Answer (score 3):

I won't address the stalling - that COULD have had any of a very wide variety of causes. That loud whining noise, though - that was just when you had the key turned to "Start", right? And it quit immediately when you released the key? If so, then it would have been the starter motor's "Bendix" (overrunning clutch for the starter drive gear) spinning... which would call for replacement of the Bendix. There's a remote possibility, too, that the ring gear on the flex plate has a broken tooth or two - that'd be made evident by a history of that sort of thing happening, but only about once per hundred starts (the ring gear has a LOT of teeth, so the chances of accidentally landing on the broken one / two are pretty slim).

The stalling... VERY hard to tell from here. Got a "Check Engine" light?